# Looking for at least one surjective ring homomorphism from $M_n(R)$ to $R$

Tags: matrices, functions, ring-theory, soft-question

Let $R$ be a ring , I am looking for a surjective ring homomporphism from $M_n(R)$ to $R$ . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: does the down voter has an answer ?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?!

Comment: I think this is hardly possible; perhaps for rings with zero multiplication ($ab=0$ for all $a,b$), but not for familiar commutative rings with identity, definitely not when $R$ is a field (in this case, matrix rings are simple).

Comment: I think if $R$ has an identity then the ideals of $M_n(R)$ are of the form $M_n(I)$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: This is just another spin on already given comments but here goes: If $R$ is a field, then $M_n(R)$ is simple, so any surjection onto $F$ is an isomorphism. But matrix rings aren't commutative for $n>1$.... so there can't be any such surjection.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a commutative ring (with unity), there is no such ring homomorphism (surjective or not), assuming it preserves unity.

Suppose that $\varphi\colon M_n(R)\to R$ is a ring homomorphism (with $n>1$). Then the kernel of $\varphi$ is of the form $M_n(I)$ where $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$. So we have the induced injective homomorphism
$$
\tilde\varphi\colon M_n(R)/M_n(I)\to R
$$
but $M_n(R)/M_n(I)$ is easily seen to be isomorphic to $M_n(R/I)$ which is non commutative when $n>1$.

In order to find an example one must find a non commutative ring $R$ having an ideal $I$ such that $M_n(R/I)$ is isomorphic to $R$, because the above argument still works the same.

If you allow rings without unity, then it is very simple: consider a free abelian group $R$ of infinite rank with zero multiplication. Then also $M_n(R)$ is a free abelian group of the same infinite rank and it is a zero ring as well. So $R$ is isomorphic to $M_n(R)$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

When $R$ is a domain and $n\geq 2$. Let's take $\phi: M_n(R)\rightarrow R$ a ring morphism. One easily see that nilpotent elements of $M_n(R)$ should be sent to $0\in R$ (because $R$ is a domain).

Let us define $E_{i,j}$ the matrix with just a $1$ at $(i,j)$ and $0$'s elsewhere.Then if $i\neq j$ we have for all $r\in R$ :

$$rE_{i,j}\text{ nilpotent so } \phi(rE_{i,j})=0 $$

$$rE_{i,i}=rE_{i,j}E_{j,i}\text{ so } \phi(rE_{i,i})=\phi(rE_{i,j})\phi(E_{j,i})=0\text{ note that you cannot do this when }n=1$$

Now for all $M\in M_n(R)$ we have :

$$\phi(M)=\phi(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nM_{i,j}E_{i,j})=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\phi(M_{i,j}E_{i,j})=0 $$

When $R$ is a domain and $n\geq 2$ there is no such morphism.

When $R$ is a commutative ring with a non-nilpotent element and $n\geq 2$. From the same argument, when $i\neq j$ and $\phi(rE_{i,j})$ is nilpotent. Furthermore $\phi(rE_{i,i})$ is thus a product of two nilpotent elements which commute because $R$ is commutative so it is nilpotent.

Finally $Im(\phi)$ is in the ring of nilpotent elements (it is a ring, again because $R$ is a commutative ring). So if $R$ happens to have a unit element then $1_R\notin Im(\phi)$.

This proves that in this larger case, one cannot find such a surjective morphism.